# How Can I Find the MIN, MAX, SUM and AVG of A Sorted List

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, readfile

The program is intended to read elements from a file then sort those elements using shell sort, save the sorted elements into an array and then find the minimum, maximum, sum and average.

So far it reads the file, sorts the elements and stores them in an array, but I can't get my head around finding the min, max, sum and avg after that.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "arrayListType.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    inFile.open("text.txt");

    arrayListType<int> list;
    arrayListType<int> newList;

    int num, counter = 0, min, max, sum = 0, avg = 0;

    while (inFile >> num)
    {
        list.insertEnd(num);
    }

    inFile.close();

    outFile.open("out.txt");


    cout << "The list before sorting:" << endl;
    list.print();
    cout << endl;

    list.shellSort();

    cout << "The list after sorting:" << endl;
    list.print();
    cout << endl;

    list = newList;


    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: SergeyA I know how to use loops for those. I just don't know how to reference the newList itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if the list is sorted then:

min is first element

max is last element

sum is add all the elements together

average (assuming you mean mean) is sum / number of elements in the list

Comment: Except when the numberof elements in the list is zero; in that case, the average is probably also zero.

Comment: Actually in that case the average is undefined. NaN.  However you are right any proper averaging code should have defined behaviour for that use case.

Comment: Yeah it might seem quite useless. I'm required to display those elements on their own (i.e the minimum of the list is:...) I know how to do the calculations, but I can't tell which to reference during the process, for example if I used a while loop to calculate the min, I'd say newList.top() is case of stacks or queues for example. That's what I'm troubled with.

Answer (score 0):

With or without sorting, you could use the brute force method:

```
int minimum = MAX_INT;
int maximum = MIN_INT;
int sum = 0; 
unsigned int quantity = 0U;
Let p = start of list;
while (p != end of list)
{
  if (p->value < minimum) minimum = p->value;
  if (p->value > maximum) maximum = p->value;
  sum = sum + p->value;
  ++quantity;
  p = p->next;
}
double average = 0.0;
if (quantity != 0)
{
  average = (double)sum / (double) quantity;
}
```

**Edit 1:**
To save some time, you can perform these calculations, the *minimum*, *maximum*, *sum* and *quantity*, while you are inserting into the list.

Which brings up the idea that a list is unnecessary unless you are going to process the values after the average is calculated.